# I no longer have privilege to comment (while reviewing)?

Tags: bug, comments, review, privileges, low-quality-posts

So, I was reviewing the *Low Quality Posts* review queue, when this item popped up in front of me: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3077103

I went down the page to see if the question was copied from a comment or something; and I found myself getting the following statement:

> add comment (requires [50 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment))
>   [image: lolololol]

I understand it *might*(?) be because I was in a review queue and all, but I think either it should show

> No comments allowed in review queues

or, pop-up a blue coloured modal (I don't remember what it is referred to as, exactly) with message similar to above one, instead of outright denying me the privilege to comment.

Comment: Or, maybe allow us to comment? Sounds like a good idea to me.